# Proving bound on recursive sequence of complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $c$ be a complex number. Define $z_{1}\left(c\right) = c$ and $z_{n+1}\left(c\right) = \left(z_{n}\left(c\right)\right)^2 + c$ for $n \geq 1$. Prove that if $\left\lvert c \right\rvert = 2 + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, then $$\left\lvert z_{n}\left(c\right) \right\rvert \geq 2 + \frac{4^{n}+2}{6}\epsilon$$

I thought induction on $n$ might work, but quickly ran into the issue that while we can write $\left\lvert z_{n}\left(c\right) \right\rvert \leq \left\lvert \left(z_{n-1}\left(c\right)\right)^2 \right\rvert + \left\lvert c \right\rvert$ by the triangle inequality, there doesn't seem to be a way to write $\left\lvert z_{n}\left(c\right) \right\rvert \geq \text{something}$ as the problem requires. So any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about the “lower triangle inequality” $|z_n| = |z_{n-1}^2 + c| \ge |z_{n-1}|^2 - |c|$ ?

Comment: Where does that inequality come from? The "reverse triangle inequality" that I'm familiar with says $\left\lvert x-y \right\rvert \geq \left\lvert \left\lvert x \right\rvert - \left\lvert y \right\rvert \right\rvert$

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: So the reverse triangle inequality gives $\left\lvert z_{n-1}^2 + c \right\rvert = \left\lvert z_{n-1}^2 - (-c) \right\rvert \geq \left\lvert \left\lvert z_{n-1}^2 \right\rvert - \left\lvert -c \right\rvert\right\rvert$. How do you get rid of the outer modulus sign?

Comment: $|z-w| \ge ||z| -|{}-w|| = ||z| - |w|| \ge |z| - |w|$

Comment: Why is $||z|−|w||≥|z|−|w|$ true?

Comment: $ |a| \ge a$ holds for all real numbers $a$.

Comment: OK got it, thanks very much indeed.

Comment: Do you know the connection of your issue with [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the “reverse triangle inequality”: If $z_{n-1}$ satisfies the estimate then
$$
|z_n| = |z_{n-1}^2 + c| \ge |z_{n-1}|^2 - |c| \\\ge  \left(2 + \frac{4^{n-1}+2}{6}\epsilon\right)^2 - (2 + \epsilon) \\
= 4 +  \frac{4^{n}+8}{6}\epsilon + \left(\frac{4^{n-1}+2}{6}\epsilon\right)^2  - (2 + \epsilon) \\
= 2 + \frac{4^{n}+2}{6}\epsilon + \left(\frac{4^{n-1}+2}{6}\epsilon\right)^2 \\
\ge 2 + \frac{4^{n}+2}{6}\epsilon \, .
$$